# Implementing radio buttons in QGIS processing scripts

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

Is it possible to implement radio buttons in QGIS 3.x processing scripts?

See also: http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/de/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html (supported parameter types for QGIS 2.8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a **selection** would work similarly to a group of radio buttons http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/de/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html

> A dropdown menu that allows the user to select from a pre-populated list. For example
>
> ```
> units=selection sq_km;sq_miles;sq_degrees
> ```